# F# | How to manage null (not Nullable) in a Match expression?

Tags: f#, null, pattern-matching

```ml
open System.Linq

type Car(model:string, color:string) =
    member this.Model = model
    member this.Color = color
    
    member this.ToString() = sprintf "ModeL:%s Color:%s" model color
    
let cars = [
    Car("Ferrari", "red")
    Car("BMW", "blu")
]

let getCar model = 
    match cars.FirstOrDefault(fun c -> c.Model = model) with
    | car -> Some(car)                       // matches ALWAYS !
    //| car when car <> null -> Some(car)
    //| car when car <> (default(Object)) -> Some(car)
    //| null -> None
    //| Null -> None     

let mercedes = getCar("Mercedes")

let car = match mercedes with
          | Some c -> c.ToString()           // c is null !!!
          | _ -> "not found"
```

`FirstOrDefault` does not return a Nullabe, so I can't match with `null`.
So, how to check the `null` returned from the function in a Match expression?

I'm using FirstOrDefault because I try to use the simplest object (Seq) from an Enumerable.
I know I can use something else starting from an Enumerable but still I like to understand what I'm missing here.

#### [Solution]

Thanks to @Abel suggestion to use `.tryFind()` I completed the task using
`Seq.tryFind()` that returns a `Car option`.

```ml
let getCar model = 
    let cars = lazy(
       // this.Collection.Indexes.List().ToEnumerable()   // this is the real data I'm using (MongoDB indexes of a collection)
       // |> Seq.map parseIndex  // a function that create Car (Index) from the BsonDocumentBsonDocument
       cars.AsEnumerable()        
    )
    cars.Value |> Seq.tryFind(fun c -> c.Model = model)
    
let mercedes = match getCar("Mercedes") with
               | Some c -> c.ToString()
               | _ -> "not found"
         
let ferrari = match getCar("Ferrari") with
              | Some c -> c.ToString()
              | _ -> "not found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in F# cannot have `null` as a proper value (it is one of the more powerful aspects of F#). However, you can break this contract by adding the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute:

```ml
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type Car(model:string, color:string) =
    member this.Model = model
    member this.Color = color
```

Now you can create instances that are `null`, and it will be easier to use it in your code when you need to interop with code that can return `null`.

Note that your code with `| car ->`  is a variable pattern, which means it catches everything and assigns the value to the variable `car`. Not sure what you want to do here, but pattern matching over classes is not very useful.

If you need to match for `null`, make that the first match, and the second match can be `car`, catching everything else. Your code would then become:

```ml
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type Car(model:string, color:string) =
    member this.Model = model
    member this.Color = color
    
    member this.ToString() = sprintf "ModeL:%s Color:%s" model color
    
module X = 
    let cars = [
        Car("Ferrari", "red")
        Car("BMW", "blu")
    ]

    let getCar model = 
        match cars.FirstOrDefault(fun c -> c.Model = model) with
        | null -> None
        | car -> Some(car)      // matches everything else
```

Another note about your code: the `Car` Type can just as well be created as a record:

```ml
type Car =
    { 
        Model: string
        Color: string
    }
```

And instead of using LINQ, it is more idiomatic to use the `List.tryFind` (or `Seq.tryFind` if you want to use an `IEnumerable`) instead, which automatically returns an option and you don't have to suddenly introduce `null` in your F# code. Your code woule then overall become a lot simpler:

```ml
type Car =
    { 
        Model: string
        Color: string
    }
    
    override this.ToString() = sprintf "ModeL:%s Color:%s" this.Model this.Color
    
module X = 
    let cars = [
        { Model = "Ferrari"; Color = "red" }
        { Model = "BMW"; Color = "blu" }
    ]

    let getCar model = cars |> List.tryFind (fun x -> x.Model = model)
```

Comment: Instead of matching on `null` and mapping to an `Option`, you could use `Option.ofObj`, which returns `None` if the object is `null` and `Some` otherwise.

Comment: @rob.earwaker, I considered that, and generally i would agree, but it wouldn't immediately help here because the F#-owned type does not support `null` and you'll get a compile error with `Option.ofObj`. It _does work_ if you have a CLI type, or have added `AllowNullLiteral`, but that's something you can only ever add to classes, not records/DU's.